# Permission Manipulation for inter-communication between modules in a monolithic app

Tags: abp

I am developing a monolithic app using ABP IO. However, I want to apply as much as I can the ethic of microservices for easy migration to that latter architectural structure.

I have respected almost all constraints including Aggregation, DDD, and so on.

For the scenario synchronous communication between services, I have used the Client proxy for the C# as it has documented and it worked perfectly except on the side of permissions. I want configurable permission that could I use to differ between internal requests that are performed between modules (future microservices) and the public requests that come from outside.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

Abp provides both dynamic proxy and static proxy (from v5.0).

Synched communication between microservices are done using Client Credentials flow. If you want to grant permission to a microservice you can either;

- Add it in seeder method (like in [this code sample](https://github.com/abpframework/eShopOnAbp/blob/657dee9c0955530170886f26673d16443912e347/services/identity/src/EShopOnAbp.IdentityService.HttpApi.Host/DbMigrations/IdentityServerDataSeeder.cs#L240)).
- Or if you are using commercial, you can use IdentityServer Management UI and add manage permissions:
  [image]

You can also check [synced communication between microservices guide](https://docs.abp.io/en/commercial/latest/startup-templates/microservice/synchronous-interservice-communication) for more information.